# Probability in duel of shots

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A and B are involved in a duel. The rules of the duel are that they are allowed to pick up their guns simultaneously. If one or both are hit, the duel ends. If both shots miss, then they repeat the process. Suppose that the results of the shots are independent and that each shot of A will hit B with probabilty $p_A$ and each shot B will hit A with probability $p_B$.
>
> d) The conditional probability that the duel ends after the nth round of shots given that A is not hit.
>
> e) The conditional probability that the duel ends after the nth round of shots given that both duelists are hit.

I know the question has already been asked here [Duel probabilty question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249358/duel-probability-question) but I'm still confused with the answers:

Firstly, it's easy to compute that $P$(A is not hit)$=\frac{p_A\,(1-p_B)}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}$

So that $P$(d)=$P$(the duel ends after the nth round|A is not hit)*$P$(A is not hit)$=(1-p_A)^{n-1}(1-p_B)^{n-1}(1-p_B)p_A/\frac{p_A\,(1-p_B)}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}=(1-p_A)^{n-1}(1-p_B)^{n-1}(1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B))$

Similarly, we have $P$(e)=$P$(the duel ends after the nth round|both are hit)*$P$(both are hit)$=(1-p_A)^{n-1}(1-p_B)^{n-1}p_Bp_A/\frac{p_A\,p_B}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}=(1-p_A)^{n-1}(1-p_B)^{n-1}(1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B))$

My confusion is: how's $P$(d)=$P$(e), what's more, they both equal to $P$(the duel ends after the nth round).

Comment: Now I think that I am able to explain my question like this: it's simpler to rephrase the question slightly:
d) $P$(both A and B miss on the first n shots given that eventually B hits and A doesn't)
e) $P$(both A and B miss on the first n shots given that both A and B are hit at same time)

Since the results of the shots are independent, this means the previous k-1 shots have no effect on the kth shot. Hence both $P$(d) and $P$(e) are equal to $P$(both A and B miss on the previous n shots)