# Ross: Why are the events A, B not independent in this problem?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A and B are involved in a duel. The rules of the
> duel are that they are to pick up their guns and
> shoot at each other simultaneously. If one or both
> are hit, then the duel is over. If both shots miss,
> then they repeat the process. Suppose that the
> results of the shots are independent and that each
> shot of A will hit B with probability $p_{A}$, and each
> shot of B will hit A with probability $p_{B}$.

(Book: Sheldon, Ross M. *A First Course in Probability*, Problem 3.63, p.107.)

Now I was wondering what the probability that the final result is that A hits B at all. Thus, letting $A$ be the event that A hits B at all, it is clear that we can condition on the number of rounds that occur after someone is shot. Letting $N_{n}$ denote that neither is hit on the nth round,

$$ P(A) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(N_{1}...N_{n-1})p_{A}=p_{A}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B}))^{n-1}$$
$$=\frac{p_{A}}{1-(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B})}$$

Similarly, if $B$ is the event that B hits A at all,

$$P(B)=\frac{p_{B}}{1-(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B})}$$

And the probability that both shoot each other is

$$P(AB)=\frac{p_{A}p_{B}}{1-(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B})}$$

Now, it is surprising to me that the events $A$ and $B$ are not independent. Namely,

$$P(AB)=\frac{p_{A}p_{B}}{1-(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B})}\neq\frac{p_{A}p_{B}}{(1-(1-p_{A})(1-p_{B}))^2}=P(A)P(B)$$

The fact that B does or doesn't shoot A should not influence the probability that A shoots B, right? What is the intuitive explanation that the events $A$ and $B$ aren't necessarily independent?

P.S: A question about the same problem in Ross's book, but doesn't answer mine: [Dual probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249358/duel-probability-question)

Comment: Of *course* the probability that $B$ hits $A$ affects the probability *AT SOME TIME* $A$ hits $B$.  Suppose the probability $B$ hits $A$ is $100\%$.  Then the probability $A$ hits $B$ is $p_A$.  Suppose instead the probability $B$ hits $A$ is $0\%$.  Then the probability $A$ hits be *eventually* is $100\%$.  These are most certainly NOT independent events.

Comment: Your expression for $P(AB)$ computes the probability that they hit each other *on the same round*. This is justified since the game ends when either person is shot, but this stopping rule is what makes the events not independent. If each player's stopping condition depended only on his own shots, then the events would indeed be independent.

Answer (score 1):

> The fact that B does or doesn't shoot A should not influence the probability that A shoots B, right?

Wrong, unless either shooter's shot is sure to hit (or sure to miss).

If the duel ends without B having shot A, then A will certainly have shot B to end the duel.

$\qquad\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)=1$

If the duel ends with B having shot A, then A may only have shot B on the final turn.

$\qquad\mathsf P(A\mid B)=p_A$

---

Thus, without invoking infinite series:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(A)&=\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)\,\mathsf P(B^\complement)+\mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex]&= 1\cdot(1- \mathsf P(B))+p_A\,\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex]&= 1-(1-p_A)\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex]&=1-q_A\,\mathsf P(B)&&\text{letting }q_A:=1-p_A, q_B:=1-p_B\\[2ex]\mathsf P(B)&=1-q_B\,\mathsf P(A)&&\text{symmetrically}\\[1ex]&=1-q_B-q_Aq_B\mathsf P(B)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1-q_B}{1-q_Aq_B}&&\text{if the denominator is non-zero}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{p_B}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}\\[2ex]\mathsf P(A)&=\dfrac{p_A}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}&&\text{symmetrically}\end{align}$